# Regex match with in the same line only

Tags: python, regex

Sample of the text am trying to solve using regex in Python is as below

```
it is amamzing to look at the evening sky and the color

color of the sky is blue

color

sky color is blue
```

Am trying to find up to 3 words previous to the ***color*** however I want to extract the words if they are only in the same line

Highlighted is the Output am looking for

```
it is amamzing to look at the evening sky and the color

color of the sky is blue

color

sky color is blue
```

Code I am using is

```
((?:\S+\s+){0,4}\b(?=color)\b\s*)
```

Sample as below

https://regex101.com/r/Q61Hi7/1

This may be a duplicate question, however I couldn't find any answer that solves

Comment: [`\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+){0,3}(?=[^\S\r\n]+color\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/Q61Hi7/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+){0,3}(?=[^\S\r\n]+color\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q61Hi7/4) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5CS%2B(%3F%3A%5B%5E%5CS%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%5CS%2B)%7B0%2C3%7D(%3F%3D%5B%5E%5CS%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2Bcolor%5Cb)):

[image]

**Details**

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+){0,3}` - zero to three occurrences of

  - `[^\S\r\n]+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces (assuming line endings are CR/LF)
  - `\S+` -  1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?=[^\S\r\n]+color\b)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be 1+ horizontal whitespaces and then a whole word `color`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/D3ZZkU):

```
import re
rx = r"\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+){0,3}(?=[^\S\r\n]+color\b)"
s = "it is amamzing to look at the evening sky and the color\ncolor of the sky is blue\ncolor\nsky color is blue"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['evening sky and the', 'sky']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\s` to match any whitespace, use a literal space to just match spaces. You could add `\t` if you want to include that too.

```
((?:\S+ ){0,4}\b(?=color)\b\s*)
```

Answer (score 1):

- the `\n` is included in `\s` that's why you read form different lines, you may use `\t` (space + tab)
- for up to 3 words, I'd say `{1,3}` to get 1, 2 or 3 words ({0,4} can read none and 4 words too)

Result in `((?:\S+[ \t]){1,3}\b(?=color)\b\s*)` https://regex101.com/r/Q61Hi7/3

Answer (score 1):

Try `(?:\S+ +){0,3}color`

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\S+` - match 1+ of non-whtespace characters (to match a word)

`+` - match 1+ spaces (you can include here other whitecharacters, but don't use `\s` as it will break your requirement of single line match, because it matches newline character as well)

`{0,3}` - match preceding pattern between 0 and 3 times

`color` - match `color` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXRBqD/1)